# set Cookie php/javascript for subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, webstore

I am making a website where we are going to sell t-shirts. All I want to do is to be able to choose a size and color and then ad to cart. The options are going to be  tags, so i want to store three values in a cookie/cookies (What shirt, what size and what color). I want to be able to access the cookie from other sites. At the checkout i just want the customer to fill in a form with name and adress and all that and all the information (the order) will be sent to our email. I don't want to involve any payment method, it will be handled another way. I have no knowledge/ experience in php and nearly none in javascript, but i as long as you describe it well, I will understand. I appreciate all help I can get :)

Comment: You have no knowledge in PHP and Javascript but want a dynamic website with cookies?, I recommend you to use a freelancer page to do this as you will probably just create a vulnerable site. Alternatively there are plenty of free stores CMS you may use

Comment: At your current experience level, be advised this project could take you roughly 100 times as long as you may expect. Get someone else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get cookies from other web-sites on different domains.

To add cookies you have to do

```
document.cookie = 'userName=User; shirtSize=xl;'
```

and so on